# I have two list and a dictionary the output should be something like this [ {dictionary values: set (g)}

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

for example if list1 has '.5' and its index in list2 is [6] and the key the on the dictionary says its normal and the result shows as following {super effective:{fire}}

```
list1 = ['1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '0.5', '1', '1', '2', '1', '0.5', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0.5']
list2 = ['bug', 'dark', 'dragon', 'electric', 'fairy', 'fight', 'fire', 'flying', 'ghost', 'grass', 'ground', 'ice', 'normal', 'poison', 'psychic', 'rock', 'steel', 'water']
dictionary = {0.25: 'super effective', 0.5: 'effective', 1: 'normal', 2: 'weak', 4: 'super weak', 0: 'resistant'}
```

Comment: Hi Skadoosh, it is pretty hard to interpret your question as it stands. If possible, please provide exactly what is required to reproduce your problem, and your desired answer plus any code you have tried to achieve your result. Thanks!

Comment: the dictionary keys have numbers. those numbers are in list1 and the outcome is the index of lst2

Comment: for example if list1 has '.5' and its index in list2 is[5] and the key the  on the dictionary says its normal  and the result shows as following {super effective:{fire}}

Comment: @Mark its typing error i fixed it

Comment: so i think you are missing your result dict which should show us what the output should be.

Comment: There's no `'.5'` in `list1`. Do you mean `'0.5'`?

Comment: result dict is empty dictionary which i will add when i finish this step

Comment: @Barmar yes its 0.5

Comment: `0.5` is at index 6, 11, and 16 in `list1`, it doesn't have an index in `list2`. Do you mean you want to get the element at the corresponding element in `list2`?

Comment: @barmar Yes, exactly. if 0.5 in index 6,11,16. the set() should include the elements in dictionary supper effective as key and element as set.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through `list1` and `list2` in parallel with `zip()`. Look up the `list1` value in `dictionary` to get the quality, use that as a key in the result, and add the `list2` value to the set it maps to.

You can use `collections.defaultdict()` or `dict.setdefault()` to create the sets as needed.

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(set)
for value, word in zip(list1, list2):
    result[dictionary[float(value)]].add(word)
```

Comment: is there a way of doing it without using defaultdict

Comment: You can use `setdefault()` or you can write an explicit `if dictionary[float(value)] in result:`

Comment: no I meant without using the module collections